# ubuntu 12.10 grub doesn't appear efi mode

Tags: grub2, windows, uefi, gpt

After a number of failed attempts on installing  Ubuntu and Linux in the hybrid-gpt of Windows, in which I wanted different partitions by gparted, I ended up creating againg a conventional partitions table within the conventional system. This photo is not mine because as creating the partition I did not think in taking photos, but I am showing you it so that you can see the format “MS-DOS”, the standard format of gparted. My neetbook is a k55MV Asus 500GB

(the page don't allow me to put 3 hiperlink I will put it at the end in a new coment

1) I installed Windows by creating a partition just for it. Windows created two partitions else for starting the system up. However creating it on ms-dos appear now in gpt view fotos
2) With the rest of the space, I created a 90-gigabyte partition for Ubuntu and the “swap” of 4 gb. The other partitions are for data.
3) I assured myself about installing Ubuntu in the partition whose format was ext4, for using that partition as base and to install the “grub” on the base of 500gb.

I have boot the system up, Ubuntu is loaded but the grub does not appear. I have tried by pressing “beginning” “UPPER CASE LETTER”, but no way! I have checked the flies up, and partitions are there.
http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-capturadepantalla-8080960.html

By pressing fdisk-1, this picture comes up:
http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-capturadepantalla-8080965.html
I am spanish

updated: at the beginning of the system, pressing f12 appears a grub without windows

Comment: http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-ajpdsoftamsdu7-8080957.html

Comment: Please indicate your [Boot-Info URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info).

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the links work; I get a message that reads "El sistema esta experimentando un error, por favor intente entrar en unas horas." That seems to be a temporary error, though....

Even if the links worked, it's critical for debugging problems like this that we have information on ***your*** system. Saying that yours is similar to somebody else's just won't cut it; there can be subtle but critical differences between the two.

Your statement that "...Ubuntu is loaded but the grub does not appear" requires clarification. I *suspect* that what you mean is that the computer boots directly into Ubuntu without first presenting you with a GRUB menu, rendering it impossible for you to boot Windows. If so, then you need to reconfigure GRUB in one way or another. If I've misinterpreted, please elaborate.

I recommend that you run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) on your system and post a link to the RESULTS.txt file that it produces. This will provide detailed information on your partition layout, enabling further diagnosis. It's likely that this is a system-specific problem that might be better handled in a Web forum (such as [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)) than here.

Comment: The solution to the problem is here http://asierhaha.blogspot.com.es/2012/10/tutorial-para-instalar-ubuntu-y-windows.html

In some days I will translate to english